# How to access a variable which is neither global nor local?

Tags: c++, scope

Look at this piece of code

```
int x = 1;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 int x = 2;
 {
  int x = 3;
  cout << x << endl;
  cout << ::x;
 }

getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When i call x from within the block i'm getting 3. When i call ::x i'm getting 1. Is it possible to call x equal to 2 from within the block?

Comment: I won't question why you would want to shadow variables like that. But it's an interesting question. +1

Comment: Mystical - it is just a curiosity of a researcher

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With cheating:

```
int x = 1;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x = 2;
    {
      int& ox = x;
      int x = 3;
      cout << x << endl;
      cout << ::x << endl;
      cout << ox << endl;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Violet: In inner scopes, the outer variables are still visible as long as you don't shadow them by creating a variable with the same name. Here, I created a reference to the outer variable before shadowing it. As such, easy access with the reference.

Comment: OP's question is about 'symbol hiding'. You must show an way to access hidden variables, such as inline ASM accessing frame pointer directly.

Comment: @9dan: "You must"? Sorry, but no. I only showed one way to access it, I even said it was kind of cheating around the requirement, and that's about it. Also, inline assembly is highly non-portable.

Answer (score 16):

No, it's not possible to do that.

Comment: I wondered how you got away with sending such a short answer; then I looked at the source.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Of course I'm serious!  If you're referring to Xeo's answer, then, as he admits, that approach is "cheating".  "No" is the correct answer.

Comment: The comment is not my answer; the comment is my workaround for SO limitations.  My answer is "No".  As far as I'm concerned, that's all that needs to be said!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No, your comment is bypassing SO's restrictions. It's like saying that your post didn't get enough upvotes, so you "worked around it" with sockpuppets. Answers have a minimum character limit for a reason; you could attempt to include some sort of an explanation with your "No" -- cite the spec or something

Comment: @Michael: It's difficult to cite the spec to demonstrate a negative.  The OP asked whether XYZ was possible; the answer is "no, it's not possible".  If it makes you happier, I can find a 30-character way of saying "no"...

Comment: "Can you see the sun during a total solar eclipse?" "No, it's not possible to do that." Seems like a prefectly valid answer.

Comment: I agree, it's not possible to dereference hidden local variables (this is the OP's main idea). C++ don't provide such functionality.